# PyDictionary translate() returns Invalid Word None

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, internal-server-error, language-translation

I made the following script called translate.py:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()
print (dictionary.meaning("indentation"))
print (dictionary.synonym("Life"))
print (dictionary.antonym("Life"))
print (dictionary.translate("Hello",'es'))
```

And I recieve the correct output for everything except

```
  print (dictionary.translate("Hello",'es')):
```

Here is my command line output:

```
macintosh-3:reorder chibb9$ python translate.py 
{u'Noun': ['a concave cut into a surface or edge (as in a coastline', 'the    formation of small pits in a surface as a consequence of corrosion', 'the space left between the margin and the start of an indented line', 'the act of cutting into an edge with toothlike notches or angular incisions']}
[u'heart', u'growth', u'soul', u'activity', u'get-up-and-go']
[u'abstract', u'idleness', u'inactivity', u'laziness', u'lethargy']
Invalid Word
None
```

I have tried the command `dictionary.translate( "[word]", "[language_code]")` many different words with different language codes and I keep getting this output for every pair:

```
Invalid Word
None
```

I have also tried using the usage web service listed on the PyDictionary github (http://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary)

But I get directed to a page that reads (picture attached, web link in image link name):

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

[http://pydictionary-geekpradd.rhcloud.com/api/translate/[code]/[word]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY0mG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDictionary uses Google Translate for translations, and as noted on the [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goslate) of the module it uses to access Google Translate, Google changed things to stop this. PyDictionary translation will not work any more.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks! It is just strange because the PyDictionary translation was working earlier this morning, (around 11am EST). Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: @SarikaHalarnakar: Searching for alternatives only turns up other tools for accessing Google Translate. Translation is a really hard problem.

Comment: I see, I am trying to assemble a dataset for the machine translation reordering problem in Spanish. I am using the Europarl corporus and I need to assemble an evaluation method. I have the target english sentence and I wanted to assemble a literal translation of the words to Spanish so that I could get a model the correct reordering in order to evaluate my reordering solution.

Comment: @SarikaHalarnakar: Oh, wait, you're just looking for individual words. You could probably find a bidirectional dictionary file to use. Googling `machine-readable translation dictionary` led me to [this page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User%3aMatthias_Buchmeier), for example.

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot, thanks. I was hoping to do the dictionary look up online  (via an api for python) so I wouldn't have to store so many large files but I guess since its not possible to use an api, this will be easier than parsing through an html of online dictionary.